# Prove that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int f_n ~d\mu = \int f ~d\mu$ in a measure space

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

In a measure space $(X,A,\mu)$ I have to prove, that:

$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \int f_n ~d\mu = \int f ~d\mu $

with $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ being a sequence of positive, measureable functions, $f(x)$ is a positive, measureable function, and $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ for all $x \in X$. Furthermore $f_n \leq f$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Now, my main issue with this is that I don't really know anything about the sequence $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ - I mean, I know that it is increasing from some point $m \in \mathbb{N}$ beacuse of the assumption of $f_n \to f$, but I can't really work out how to show the above from just that.

I am, however, given the hint, that $\lim \sup_{n \to \infty} \int f_n~d\mu \leq \sup_{n\to \infty} \int f_n ~d\mu$, but I'm not sure how to use that really.

I'm really drawing a blank here - any help and tips would be greatly appreciated! :-)

Comment: Can you use Fatou's lemma ?

Comment: Also, check out Dominated Convergence Theorem and Monotone Convergence Theorem.

Answer (score 3):

Becaue $f_n\leq f,\forall  n\in\mathbb N\Rightarrow \int{f_n}\leq \int f,\forall n\in\mathbb N\Rightarrow \limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}{\int{f_n}}\leq \sup\limits_{n}{\int{f_n}}\leq \int{f}\,\,\,\,(1)$

From the other hand, using Fatou's lemma we get $\int{f}=\int{\lim_{n\to\infty}{f_n}}=\int{\liminf_{n\to\infty}{f_n}}\leq \liminf_{n\to\infty}{\int{f_n}}\,\,\,(2)$

Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get 
$$\int{f}\leq \liminf_{n\to\infty}{\int{f_n}}\leq \limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}{\int{f_n}}\leq \sup\limits_{n}{\int{f_n}}\leq \int{f}$$
Therefore, the limit exists and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{\int{f_n}}=\int{f}$